# Split dataset, apply different operation on each group, and then combine

Tags: r, data.table, plyr, dplyr

I am using the code below to split a dataset into two and perform a similar operation on each half. The two results are then merged back together.  I know I might be describing the split-apply-combine framework, but I am unable to think of how I might streamline the code below.

The dataset has 4 variables that are to be updated. Each of the 4 variables has a formula to calculate the new value, with a different formula for each half, for a total of 8 formulas.

Might the code below be improved by some level of vectorization? It seems to be more verbose than necessary. I am unsure on how to perform different operations (i.e. use different formulas) for each of the split halves, except for the way below.

```
data <- structure(list(site = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), plot = 1:6, 
    C = c(40L, 30L, 10L, 5L, 0L, 0L), E = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 
    20L, 45L), M = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L), P = c(1000L, 900L, 
    800L, 500L, 200L, 50L), FF = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("site", 
"plot", "C", "E", "M", "P", "FF"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)) 

df1 <- data[data$FF == 1,]
df0 <- data[data$FF == 0,]

df1$C <- df1$C * 1.1
df1$E <- df1$E * 0.9
df1$M <- df1$M * 0.1
df1$P <- df1$P * 1.01

df0$C <- df0$C * 0.8
df0$E <- df0$E * 1.05
df0$M <- df0$M * 1.01
df0$P <- df0$P * 1.01

df.new <- rbind(df1, df0)
```

Comment: Wait, you tagged this with plyr and data.table but haven't explored how to use them yet?

Comment: I did explore plyr and data.table via other SO questions and answers, and some feeble attempts which I didn't reproduce here. However, I thought that either seemed appropriate if I had the wherewithal to write code with them. I can post the non-functional code snippets. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many tools for split-apply-combine in R. I'd be inclined to use the data.table package:

```
require(data.table)
mydt <- data.table(data)
mycols <- c('C','E','M','P')
newcols <- paste0(mycols,'new')
my1vec <- c(1.1,.9,1,1.01)
my0vec <- c(.8,1.05,1.01,1.01)

mydt[FF==1,(newcols):=mapply(`*`,my1vec,.SD,SIMPLIFY=FALSE),.SDcols=mycols]
mydt[FF==0,(newcols):=mapply(`*`,my0vec,.SD,SIMPLIFY=FALSE),.SDcols=mycols]
```

I put the new values in new columns. If instead you want to overwrite the old values (as the original code does), use `(mycols)` in place of `(newcols)`.

Answer (score 2):

Combine `by` and `do.call` like this:

```
do.call(rbind,
  by(data,data$FF,
    function(data)data*matrix(c(1,1,.8,1.05,1.01,1.01,1),
      ncol=ncol(data),nrow=nrow(data),byrow=TRUE)))
```

That is, split your `data` along `data$FF` using `by`. Multiply each chunk entrywise by an appropriate matrix (that's the anonymous `function`). Finally, `do.call` the `rbind` function to bind the result together rowwise.

Sort the result by the `FF` column if desired.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `within` and use `FF` as a numeric variable. It's not as short as some of the answers, but it is a bit more verbose.

```
df.new <- within(data, {
  C = C * (0.8 + 0.3 * FF)
  E = E * (1.05 - 0.15 * FF)
  M = M * (1.01 - 0.91 * FF) 
  P = P * 1.01 })
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a simpler way to do it but I think these 4 lines do what you want:

```
df.new = data
df.new$C = ifelse(data$FF==1,data$C*1.1,data$C*0.8)
df.new$E = ifelse(data$FF==1,data$E*0.9,data$E*1.05)
df.new$M = ifelse(data$FF==1,data$M*0.1,data$M*1.01)
df.new$P = ifelse(data$FF==1,data$P*1.01,data$P*1.01)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#define the coefficients in the FF==1 case
FF1coeffs<-c(1.1,0.9,0.1,1.01)
#define the coefficients in the FF==0 case
FF0coeffs<-c(0.8,1.05,1.01,1.01)
#multiply
data[,3:6]*(rep(FF1coeffs,each=nrow(data))*data$FF+(1-data$FF)*rep(FF0coeffs,each=nrow(data)))
```